# Resize Table inside Kendo Editor using Angular 7

Tags: angular7, kendo-editor

I am using a Kendo Editor in my angular 7 application. I can insert table inside the editor from editor toolbar. But I can not resize the table, even I can not select the table. I need this using kendo editor with angular 7. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you share some code samples, it will be easier for others to help point you in the right direction.